# Setting variables from within a map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
let pa = 0;
let pw = 0;
let pc = 0;
let pi = 0;
let pr = 0;

this.state.array.data.map((i) => {
  if (i.mdn === this.queryParams.mdn && i.sources != null) {
    return (i.sources.map((sources) => {
      if (sources.source.toString().toLowerCase() === "a") {
        pa = sources.t.sessions.u
      }
      if (sources.source.toString().toLowerCase() === "w") {
        pw = sources.t.sessions.u
      }
      if (sources.source.toString().toLowerCase() === "c") {
        pc = sources.t.sessions.u
      }
      if (sources.source.toString().toLowerCase() === "i") {
        pi = sources.t.sessions.u
      }
      if (sources.source.toString().toLowerCase() === "r") {
        pr = sources.t.sessions.u
      }
    }))
  }
},

this.setState({
  web: [],
  app: [],
  preference: [{a: pa}, {w: pw}, {c: pc}, {i: pi}, {r: pr}]
}),
```

Once I get to set state, it doesn't actually set it, it just takes the 0 and throw throws in there.

Comment: A map that modifies state is a bad idea. You probably should use a `forEach` instead. Map should return a new array without affecting the rest of the code. The code as it stands is very confusing.

Comment: In combination with what @JuanMendes suggested, you could really make this a lot cleaner by replacing your `if` statements with a switch. it would allow you to replace all of your `...toString().toLowerCase()` calls with 1.

Comment: You are setting a global variable... `preferenceApp` and the others are global

Comment: `i.sources.map((sources)` - You have the parameter named `sources` and you're calling map on `sources`. You should change the parameter to `source` or something different.

Comment: @EvanBechtol Not everyone agrees with you that a `switch` is cleaner, all the breaks you need to add in there. Having said that, they should at least be `if/elses `to make it clearer

Comment: @JuanMendes switch is cleaner IMO because the code repeats so much...

Comment: I suggested a switch purely based on the fact that it would reduce the number of function calls, which are just repeating the same action over and over. It's a bit sloppy IMO.

Comment: i replaced the variable names to cut down on code. i appreciate the switch idea, i can do that... but again, im not looking for complaints about awfully written code, just a solution.

Comment: map os to take an array and change it into something else. You are using it as a forLoop....

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing a sample of `array.data`, but you might want to check [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Is there a reason for an array with all these objects rather than a single object with various keys: `[{a: pa}, {w: pw}, {c: pc}, {i: pi}, {r: pr}]`? If this were a single object a lot this code could go away. It's odd to have all these different keys without being able to reference any of them without searching the array,

Comment: @MarkMeyer i eventually have to look at them and pick the one with the highest number. I figure an array would be easier... and i need to know which item has the biggest num

Comment: If you do not need all the values up front, than no it would be easier when you are setting it to not set one that is lower...

Comment: @epascarello I realize some people like switches, but it is a preference. If the OP creates a variable for `sources.source.toString().toLowerCase()` then it's not so bad

Comment: i have a lot of other code with switches. switch is definately easier. i just started working on this portion of it, my PROBLEM is being able to set variables with values...

Comment: why not setState inside the map callback function itself rather than executing it as the thisArg for modified object ? My guess would be that the callback is still executing on the initial object rather than the modified object.

Comment: is there more than one key "a"?

Comment: Is there only one match for `i.mdn === this.queryParams.md`????

Comment: no, there is not more than 1 a. and the MDN that was thrown into the query may not be in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Array.prototype.map`, try `Array.prototype.forEach` and set a preference object by key.

To preserve the order of the keys, create an array of your desired order.

```js
let order = [ 'a', 'w', 'c', 'i', 'r' ];
    preference = {
      a : 0,
      w : 0,
      c : 0,
      i : 0,
      r : 0 
    };

this.state.array.data.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.mdn === this.queryParams.mdn && item.sources != null) {
    return item.sources.forEach((entry) => {
      var key = entry.source.toString().toLowerCase();
      preference[key] = entry.t.sessions.u;
    });
  }
});

this.setState({
  web: [],
  app: [],
  preference: order.map(key => ({ [key] : preference[key] }));
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making big assumptions here since you never gave the input and I am just going off things you mentioned in the comments.

What I really think it should be now that I think about it is a simple find and a map

```
const lookup = []
const data = this.state.array.data

const content = data.find(obj => obj.mdn === this.queryParams.mdn && obj.sources
let preferences = defaultValues //<-- define defaultValues
if (content) {
  preferences = content.sources.map(({source, t}) =>
    ({ [lookup[source.toLowerCase()]] : t.sessions.u })
}
this.setState({ preferences })
```

if mdn can be in more than one, than it would require forEach and some other additional logic.

Answer (score -1):

As Juan Mendes pointed out; if there is only one item to find per variable, you can simply use a find operation specific to that variable. For each variable it would look something like this;

```js
const someArray = [{ property: "a", text: "lorem"}, { property: "b", text: "ipsum"}]

const pa = someArray.find(function(item) {
  return item.property === 'a'
})

console.log(pa)
```

In case you don't have exactly one find operation; use Array.forEach() instead of Array.map(), as the callback in map should return a value, whereas you can modify a (different) variable using forEach.

For example:

```js
let pa = 0

const someArray = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor']
someArray.forEach(function(word) {
  pa = word
})

console.log(pa)
```

Comment: It's a good suggestion but doesn't address the problem, does it?

Comment: It does, because (without more code shown in the OP) I'm assuming that `setState()` isn't actually broken. Since it's usually part of react or some other library.

Comment: I don't think that this answer has enough of OP's code to really show that it truly answers the question posed. The question is not regarding the `setState` call, but more to do with the map.

Comment: The OP's post clearly states: "Once I get to set state, it doesn't actually set it, it just takes the 0 and throw throws in there."

Comment: This is not a great example, it should really be `const ba = someArray.find(work => someCondition(word))`